# Unable to install cocoapods

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Hi I am learning React Native, I was able to build Android version successfully but here in the iOS version I am facing so many issues. I'm developing a Podcast application for both Android and iOS but when I'm trying to install `cocoapods` in my Application I am getting the following error,

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20201214-42573-vm30sv.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/json-2.3.1/gem_make.out
```

Hardware: Mac Mini

Can anyone help me in solving this issue. I'd like to install it with `sudo gem install cocoapods` rather than `brew`

Comment: You don't have to use `brew` to install `cocoapods`, but the fact that you have to say `sudo` is a Bad Smell. You need to get control of your ruby immediately and stop using the system ruby. You should install `rbenv` and get yourself a personal ruby. See https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/ - you don't have to do exactly what I'm saying if you really hate homebrew, but if you do in fact do exactly what I'm saying, you will be able to get cocoapods working.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use Apple's Ruby installation. That installation exists *solely* for internal use by Apple itself.

Since you have specified in your question that you want to use Apple's Ruby installation, I am afraid there is nothing that can be done to fix the problem.

If, on the other hand, you are willing to use a different Ruby [installation](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/) (installed [by hand](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source), with [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby), with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install), with [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build), with [RVM](https://rvm.io/), [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/), or any other way), then the problem should not present itself in the first place.

For more information, see for example

- [macOS 10.15 Catalina Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes#Scripting-Language-Runtimes)
- [PSA: Do not use system Ruby](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby)
- [Why you shouldn't use the System Ruby](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby)
- [If possible, do not use the ruby system version on Mac OSX](https://egel.github.io/2018/11/10/if-possible-do-not-use-the-ruby-system-version-on-mac-osx.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install Xcode Command Line Tools。
command:
xcode-select --install